# C Array acting strange when it pass the number of arguments

Tags: c

I was implementing Command-line arguments with C , And I shocked when the Arguments Array start acting strange when it passes the number of the argument given. here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int a, char *arra[]){

      /*
     for(int i = 1;i<a;i++){
           printf("Arguments N%d -> %s\n",i+1,arra[i]);
      }
      printf("Totale Arguments:%d\n",a-1);

      */  

      for(int i = 0;i<=49 ;i++){
             printf("%d: -> %s\n-------------------------------------- 
             ------\n",i,arra[i]);
       }
      return 0;
 }
```

My question is how did the array have access to the Linux Terminal variable like the Path variable PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

And the Output was like :

```
 0: -> ./list
--------------------------------------------
1: -> hi
--------------------------------------------
2: -> 234
--------------------------------------------
3: -> hello
--------------------------------------------
4: -> (null)
--------------------------------------------
5: -> LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
--------------------------------------------
6: -> XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
--------------------------------------------
7: -> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
--------------------------------------------
8: -> GDM_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
--------------------------------------------
9: -> DISPLAY=:1
--------------------------------------------
10: -> COLORTERM=truecolor
--------------------------------------------
11: -> USERNAME=root
--------------------------------------------
12: -> XDG_VTNR=2
--------------------------------------------
13: -> SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/0/keyring/ssh
--------------------------------------------
14: -> XDG_SESSION_ID=7
--------------------------------------------
15: -> USER=root
--------------------------------------------
16: -> DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
--------------------------------------------
17: -> GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/bbdf3fc7_241a_437d_86d0_982594cbb92d
--------------------------------------------
18: -> PWD=/root/Documents/Programming/c
--------------------------------------------
19: -> HOME=/root
--------------------------------------------
20: -> SSH_AGENT_PID=1581
--------------------------------------------
21: -> QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
--------------------------------------------
22: -> XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
--------------------------------------------
23: -> XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
--------------------------------------------
24: -> XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome
--------------------------------------------
25: -> GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT=stderr
--------------------------------------------
26: -> GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
--------------------------------------------
27: -> WINDOWPATH=2
--------------------------------------------
28: -> TERM=xterm-256color
--------------------------------------------
29: -> SHELL=/bin/bash
--------------------------------------------
30: -> VTE_VERSION=5202
--------------------------------------------
31: -> XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
--------------------------------------------
32: -> GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
--------------------------------------------
33: -> GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.67
--------------------------------------------
34: -> SHLVL=1
--------------------------------------------
35: -> XDG_SEAT=seat0
--------------------------------------------
36: -> GDMSESSION=gnome
--------------------------------------------
37: -> GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
--------------------------------------------
38: -> LOGNAME=root
--------------------------------------------
39: -> DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
--------------------------------------------
40: -> XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
--------------------------------------------
41: -> XAUTHORITY=/run/user/0/gdm/Xauthority
--------------------------------------------
42: -> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
--------------------------------------------
43: -> GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS=JS ERROR;JS LOG
--------------------------------------------
44: -> SESSION_MANAGER=local/FXMACO:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1529,unix/FXMACO:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1529
--------------------------------------------
45: -> _=./list
--------------------------------------------
46: -> OLDPWD=/root/Documents/Books
--------------------------------------------
47: -> (null)
--------------------------------------------
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: undefined behavior is allowed to act strange.

Comment: or.... maybe it won't. or maybe, just maybe, a universal solution to the halting problem will be divulged.

Comment: [Garbage In Garbage Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)

Comment: It is common behaviour for pointers to the environment variables to be stored immediately after the null pointer at the end of the `argv` array that is passed to `main()`.  However, it is not required by any standard that the layout works that way — you are, as others said, invoking undefined behaviour by reading beyond the end of the `argv` array (which is the array your code calls `arra`; that's a legal name change and entirely your prerogative, but the conventional names for the arguments are `argc` and `argv` and there's not often a good reason to deviate from the conventional).

Comment: Thank you all for your help !! But the more import thing how did the array have access to the Linux Terminal variable like the Path variable PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: It was incidental. the char ** array pointing to those strings was by accident placed just after the  argv. It could be anything, or you could get the segfault earlier. It is UB and anything can happen

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable is part of the execution environment; it does not belong to the terminal emulator. The application can see its value using `getenv()` or by iterating over the global `environ`. It can change the value (in its own execution environment, which will, by default, be copied into its childrens' environments) using `setenv()` or `putenv()`. All of these have manpages. In short, there is no security issue here.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0;i<=49 ;i++){
```

as we see here your argument list is shorter than 50 elements

It is good to use standard names and to take into the account number of arguments passed (that is the reason of the `argc`)

```
int main(int argc char *argv[])
{

    for(int i = 0;i < argc ;i++){
```